# example of maximal operator that is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis

We know that there are **no** nonzero functions $f \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $Mf \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$, where $Mf$ is the Hardy Littlewood maximal function.

Can we find a maximal operator that is integrable for nonzero functions?

More precisely, I would really appreciate some help with the following:

> Let $ \phi \in C^\alpha (\mathbb R^n) \cap L^1 (\mathbb R^n) $ and set
>    $ \displaystyle  M_\phi f(x) := \sup_{t>0} f * \phi_t $,  where
>    $\displaystyle \phi_t (\cdot)= \frac{1}{t^n} \phi \left( \frac{ \cdot}
>  {t} \right)$.
>
> Show that while $\displaystyle |M_\phi| \lesssim Mf $  there exist
>   nonzero function $f \in L^1(R^n)$ such that $ M_\phi f \in L^1 $

Any ideas?

Thanking in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you please give some more details? Thank you!

Comment: @Jose27: All the maximal function characterizations of $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ that I've seen in references are with very nice functions $\phi$ such as Schwartz functions. Would you please provide me with a reference for a characterization done with a more general function as in the question statement?

Comment: @passenger: I know this question of yours dates from several months ago--and you may no longer be interested in it--but would you please briefly comment on if the full generality of $\phi\in C^{\alpha}\cap L^{1}$ is necessary? I find this question very interesting, but I have struggled in coming up with an answer except under a slightly more restrictive condition for $\phi$.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig Actually it need not be true that $M_\phi f\le cMf$. The example in that other thread shows that $M_\phi f(x)$ can tend to zero as slowly as you want as $x\to\infty$; in particular $M_\phi f$ need not be in weak $L^1$. Example will be appearing in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366738/integrability-of-maximal-convolution-operator?noredirect=1#comment2781783_1366738 very soon...

Comment: @MattRosenzweig: Sorry, I thought you could do away with most of the regularity in the maximal characterizations, but apparently not so drastically.